# How to manually install umbraco on webhosting?

Tags: content-management-system, installation, umbraco, webmatrix, shared-hosting

How to manually install umbraco on webhosting?

I purchased asp.net web hosting through arvixe, which provide umbraco installation (one time free, and charge for any additional upgrades like installing extensions).

They provide a one click installer through web gallery, which states that umbraco 4.9

However, I am just as confused to HOW and WHERE to start installing umbraco to web host.

**I successfully installed on my local pc thru' web matrix, but what about here (web hosting), there is just web gallery. What should I do? Am I missing anything? Please help.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use FTP to copy your local installation to your webserver, modify the web.config to point to the new database and your website should be up and running.

Comment: Thank you. Will the extension - ucomponents, will also get installed as I have installed it and used as a part of my project in my local pc?

Comment: You just need to upload the umbraco files to your root folder. For the installation, please refer to http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/how-to-install-umbraco-on-windows-server-2008. You need to create your database on Control panel first.